# How do you map a repeated set of radio buttons to an array on an Angular controller's model?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For example, I have a controller with an array property called `'houses'` and I am `ng-repeat`-ing that on a table row with set of radio buttons (true/false, or what have you). What should the model be on those radio buttons such that selecting any of them will set the value on the corresponding item in the model array? I've tried setting the model to something like:

```
ng-model="array[{{$index}}]"
```

But that didn't work. I took out the `{{ }}` and was simply left with the literal string '$index'.

Is this even possible in Angular?

Comment: Wait - Are you referring to check boxes or radio buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work without the curling brackets. I made a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/X0V05iKmx15fs91tvtmF?p=preview).

```js
$scope.houses = [true, false, true, false, false];
```

```html
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="house in houses">
    Checked: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="houses[$index]" />
  </li>
</ul>

{{houses}}
```

I didn't understood if you have a complex object and wants to set its property (i.e. `ng-model="houses[$index].checked"`. If this is the case, than you should just use the iterator (i.e. `ng-model="house.checked"`), as `house` will iterate over each of the array objects.

Comment: Second part of your answer worked. The first one as I recall didn't work, but I'd have to check again.

Comment: The Plunker I posted is implementing the first part, it does work, if you want to store only the states.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is an [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/305) open for this particular case. It seems that is not possible,  the radio button have their own scope due to the `ng-repeat`.

There is an alternative solution using the checked attribute : [see code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/970934)

Comment: Not sure but the OP might have been referring to checkboxes instead